# How to get output of the values that are not matched in filter function in Apache flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I am newbie to Apache flink i am trying to filter words that starts with letter "N" and i am getting output but how can i get words which don't starts with word "N" below is the code i am using

```
package DataStream;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FilterFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;

public class WordStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> inputData = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

        DataStream<String> filterData = inputData.filter(new FilterFunction<String>() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean filter(String value) throws Exception {
                return value.startsWith("N");
            }
        });

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tokenize = filterData
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {

                    @Override
                    public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) throws Exception {
                        out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(value, Integer.valueOf(1)));

                    }
                });

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> counts = tokenize.keyBy(0).sum(1);

        counts.print();

        env.execute("WordStream");

    }

}
```

Can you suggest how to capture not matched words to another stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can make use of [side-output](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/side_output.html) to achieve this. Just emit the matched elements in actual collector and unmatched element with side-output tag using ProcessFunction, then fetch the side-output elements from the main stream.

For an example, your code can be changed something like this,

```
package datastream;


import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.ProcessFunction;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.apache.flink.util.OutputTag;

public class WordStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> inputData = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);

        // Initialize side-output tag to collect the un-matched elements 
        OutputTag<Tuple2<String, Integer>> unMatchedSideOutput = new OutputTag<Tuple2<String, Integer>>("unmatched-side-output") {};

        SingleOutputStreamOperator<Tuple2<String, Integer>> tokenize = inputData
                .process(new ProcessFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
                        if (value.startsWith("N")) {
                            // Emit the data to actual collector
                            out.collect(new Tuple2<>("Matched=" + value, Integer.valueOf(1)));
                        } else {
                            // Emit the un-matched data to side output
                            ctx.output(unMatchedSideOutput, new Tuple2<>("UnMatched=" + value, Integer.valueOf(1)));
                        }
                    }
                });

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> count = tokenize.keyBy(0).sum(1);

        // Fetch the un-matched element using side-output tag and process it
        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> unMatchedCount = tokenize.getSideOutput(unMatchedSideOutput).keyBy(0).sum(1);

        count.print();

        unMatchedCount.print();

        env.execute("WordStream");

    }
}
```

**Note:** I slightly changed the emitted value with prefix `Matched=` and `UnMatched=` to get the clear understanding in the output.

For the below input,

```
Hello
Nevermind
Hello
```

I get the following output,

```
3> (UnMatched=Hello,1)
4> (Matched=Nevermind,1)
3> (UnMatched=Hello,2)
```

Comment: is it possible to do same thing with Filterfunction without using processfunction

Comment: Nope, you can't because, [filter method interface](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-core/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/FilterFunction.java#L59) doesn't provides you the context object to emit by yourself. Thats the reason we have to use [ProcessFunction](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/ProcessFunction.java#L70) which provides you rich objects like Context and Collector.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution:

```java
DataStream<String> nwords = input.filter(s -> startsWith("N"));
DataStream<String> others = input.filter(s -> !startsWith("N"));
```

I believe this is slightly less efficient than the solution using a side output, but it will still run in a single task, using operator chaining, so it also requires no ser/de overhead, or networking.

Don't get me wrong -- in general side outputs are the way to go for splitting streams.